# (Closed) Solve Differential equation with known solution in one case

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\eta \in ]0,1]$ and
$$g(x) = \frac{ 1}{1+\eta \sqrt{1+ x^2}}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
The differential equation to solve is
$$g(y')y'y=- x.\tag{1}$$
Numerical studies indicate that there are two solutions. One of them is given by the half-circle with radius $R>0$
$$y(x) = \pm(\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} + R \eta), \ x\in [-R,R].$$
I'm struggling to find the other one.

Properties I found so far:

- if $y$ is a solution then also $a y(x/a), -y, y(-x)$

**Question closed: It turned out there is no second solution!! Was just another bug in Mathematica software.**

Comment: Why should this have a real analysis tag? Looks like a (horrendous) ODE to me.

Comment: The description reads 'This tag can also be used for more advanced topics'.

Comment: But this is not more advanced. It's highly technical and likely to have no closed form solution, but I see no techniques of real analysis here.

Comment: Don't think so, as it has a simple solution (at least in one case). Checking solutions or doing separation of variables requires differentiation/integration.

Comment: Why $y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ is an "emisphere"?

Comment: A hemisphere in 1 dimension = half-circle.

Comment: I strongly doubt that a closed form nice solution exists. Even for the linearized version $g(x)=1-\eta \sqrt{x^2+1}$ *Mathematica* doesn't give exact solutions.

Comment: If $y$ is a solution, then $z(x)=a\cdot y(x/a)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Can confirm that the half-circle formula does solve the ODE (assisted by Mathematica). Do you at least have a graph of this other family of solutions?

Comment: @GoodBoy Yes, its extremely close to $- a x^2+b$, $a,b>0$ depending on $\eta$.

Comment: By differentiating the equation one can show that $y^{(2n)}(0)=a_n \left(\frac{1+\eta}{y(0)}\right)^{2n-1}$ and $y^{(2n+1)}(0)=0$.

Comment: Are you sure there is another solution? Knowing that $y'(0) = 0$, the derivative of the original ODE at $x = 0$ is $(y''(0)y(0))\frac{1}{1+n}=-1$, which means that $y''(0) = \frac{-(1+n)}{y(0)}$, which is exactly the same as with the half-circle. Even after writing it as $\left(y^{2}-x^{2}\eta^{2}\right)(y')^{2}+\left(2xy\right)y'+x^{2}\left(1-\eta^{2}\right)=0$ and writing a series for $y$, I only get the solutions you get (and an extraneous one for the other half of the circle that doesn't work).

Comment: Right, see my edit in the question.